# Nest JS: How to correctly define a redirect using @Redirect director. The documentation looks incomplete

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Im working through Nest JS docs and the @Redirect example is not working as presented here: https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#redirection

The exact instruction and code presented is:

```
@Redirect() takes two arguments, url and statusCode, both are optional. The default value of statusCode is 302 (Found) if omitted.

@Get()
@Redirect('https://nestjs.com', 301)
```

I would expect this to fail as the example isnt decorating a function but says to use the decorator itself to perform the redirect. The predictably causes errors:

Using the documented code inside a controller:

```
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) { }

  @Get()
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }

  @Get('docs')
  @Redirect('https://docs.nestjs.com', 302)
 }
```

Typescript error: Declaration expected.ts(1146)

build error :

```
17|nest-nest1  | TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
17|nest-nest1  |     at Module.addController (/app/nest/nest1/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/module.js:298:30)
17|nest-nest1  |     at NestContainer.addController (/app/nest/nest1/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/container.js:134:19)
17|nest-nest1  |     at DependenciesScanner.insertController (/app/nest/nest1/node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:232:24)17|nest-nest1  |     at /app/nest/nest1/node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:113:18
17|nest-nest1  |     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
17|nest-nest1  |     at DependenciesScanner.reflectControllers (/app/nest/nest1/node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:112:21)
17|nest-nest1  |     at DependenciesScanner.scanModulesForDependencies (/app/nest/nest1/node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:84:18)
17|nest-nest1  |     at async DependenciesScanner.scan (/app/nest/nest1/node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:28:9)
17|nest-nest1  |     at async /app/nest/nest1/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-factory.js:95:17
17|nest-nest1  |     at async Function.asyncRun (/app/nest/nest1/node_modules/@nestjs/core/errors/exceptions-zone.js:22:13
```

Clearly something is missing from the code example so how do I implement a working redirect using the redirect decorator?

Answer (score 1):

The correct and complete minimal answer (gleaned from here not the documentation) is:

```
  @Redirect('/dogs', 302)
  redirect() { }
```

IMHO this looks like a very convoluted and verbose way of simply writing something like this

```
redirect("/dogs", ...)
```

though Im still trying to understand why nest.js is using decorators EVERYWHERE when simple function definitions (a la express) can express things far more succinctly.